# How to pass two dimensions array to a function and how to call it

Tags: c++, arrays

I've tried many time to pass the array to a function then do some calculation such as getting the total of the columns, the problem is I don't know how to call the result form the function, usually I get errors.

this is just one code I'm trying to solve it from yesterday :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//prototype
int get_total(int whatever[][2], int row);

int main ()
{
    const int row=2;
    const int col=3;

    int marks[row][col];

    // this is prompt the user to input the values
    for (int i=0; i<row;i++)
    {
        for (int p=0; p<col; p++)
        {
            cin >> marks[i][p];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // this is just display what the user input as a table
    for (int x=0; x< row ; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<col ; y++)
        {
            cout << marks[x][y] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int sum;

    // this is the most important thing I want to know,
    // how to call the function :(
    sum=get_total(marks,row);

    return 0;
}

// to get the total of each columns
const int row=3;
// not sure if the declaration is correct or not :(

int get_total(int whatever[][2], int row)
{
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int p=0; p < 3; p++)
            int total=0;
        //this line is completly wrong, How can I calculate the total of columns?
        total+=get_total[2][p];
    }
    // do we write return total ?
    // I'm not sure because we need the total for each column

    return total;
}
```

sorry for the mess, and I appreciate any help to explain passing the multidimensions arry to a function as parameter and how to call the function>

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Actually, I just did that, and now it should be clear why this code is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int marks[row][col]
```

This means that `marks` has type `int[2][3]`.

```
int get_total(int whatever[][2], int row);
```

You've however declared `get_total` to accept an `int(*)[2]`. `int[2][3]` can decay to `int(*)[3]` but that is not compatible with `int(*)[2]`, hence why you can't pass `marks` to `get_total`. You can instead declare `get_total` to accept an `int(*)[3]`:

```
int get_total(int whatever[][3], int row);
// equivalent to:
int get_total(int (*whatever)[3], int row);
```

If you instead decide to declare `get_total` to accept an `int**` or an `int*`, then you can't legally pass `marks` to it in the former case, and you can't legally iterate over the whole multidimensional array in the latter. Consider not using arrays, it's simpler this way.

Comment: thank you guys I was confused, now I've got the idea completely, I appreciate ur helping one by one. just there is someone I think he is angry, I want to say to him, sorry if my ignorance annoys you. you still a teacher who must be respected by students.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays decay to pointers when calling functions.

You can do 2 things:

- Pass the number of lines and columns as arguments to the function.
- Use `std::vector` instead. I suggest you take a look at it, it'll do the trick and you'll learn something new and very useful.

Also, your function should do this:

```
int get_total(int** whatever)
{
    //total is 0 at the beginning 
    int total=0;
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int p=0; p < 3; p++)
            //go through each element and add it to the total
            total+=whatever[i][p];
    }    
    return total;
}
```

This will return the total for the whole matrix, I'm assuming that's what you mean by `getting the total of the columns`

Comment: that is fantastic information, just I want to ask about how to call the function, you said I have to pass the number of rows and columns as parameters, is that right?  the problem is how to call the function again normally without using pointer, this is my trying, can you tell where is the missing part in the line:        sum=get_total(marks,row);

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'call the function again normally'... you can call the function as many times as you want: get_total(marks,row);get_total(marks,row);get_total(marks,row);... the same way you did it the first time. Can you be more explicit on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Arrays **decay to** pointers. "Deprecated" has a technical meaning in programming that is nonsensical here.